# finding the flow of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Solve this differential equation

$$x^{\prime}=\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},$$
$$y^{\prime}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
in $A=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\in[1,4]\}$. 
Could help me get the general equation for the flow in A?

Comment: the trajectories are concentric circles centered at the origin.

Comment: exact! but I wonder if an explicit representation possible. Since I want to compare the separation of the trajectories of different points

Comment: Note that $xx' + yy' = 0 \implies (x^2+y^2)' = 0$ so $x^2+y^2 = r^2$ where $r$ is determined by the initial conditions. Substitute this back into the ODE to get a simple system which can be further reduced to two simple second order ODEs whose solution is well-known.

Comment: very true , I had not realized in such detail ! Thank you